# How can I write to my CSV file in my booking system [STUCK]

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I know I sound absolutely stupid but i'm new to Python and as my school project I have to create a cinema booking system.

I have decided that I'm going to write to a CSV file in the format:

```
 ,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
A,+,+,+,+,+,+,+
B,+,+,+,-,+,+,+
C,+,+,+,-,+,+,+
D,+,+,+,-,+,+,+
E,+,+,+,-,+,+,+
```

' + ' meaning seat free

' - ' meaning seat doesn't exist

' * ' meaning seat booked

Will it be easy for me to be able to read from this and check whether for example row A at column 1 is Free and if so set them to * meaning they will be booked...

If it i possible I would be much obliged if someone could point me in the correct direction.

I have no problem with the rest it's just I've hit a barrier and my mind is blank hours of researching and googling can't solve this for me. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: That's a terrible idea! What if you have 10000 seats how would you do that?

Comment: If you are not required to write to a file consider using a `dict`

Comment: Maybe an alternative to CSV?

Comment: but I only have that many seats

Comment: oh yes a dictionary of course will look into it

Comment: And if humans never have to read it consider just using a list of strings. Python will index them by character by default.

Comment: You'll eventually need to store the information somewhere. Have you ever head about Sparse Matrices per example?

Comment: `seats = {(x,y):"x"for x in ["A","B","C","D","E"] for y in range(1,8)}`

Comment: Thank you everyone I think I was misunderstood it was just the creating of the table I was struggling with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seating should be A,1 A,2 etc..

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
missing = (("B",4),("C",4),("D",4),("E",4))

seats = {(x,y):"x" if (x,y) not in missing else "-" for x in ["A","B","C","D","E"] for y in range(1,8)}

pp(seats)
{('A', '1'): '+',
 ('A', '2'): '+',
 ('A', '3'): '+',
 ('A', '4'): '+',
 ('A', '5'): '+',
 ('A', '6'): '+',
 ('A', '7'): '+',
 ('B', '1'): '+',
 ('B', '2'): '+',
 ('B', '3'): '+',
 ('B', '4'): '-',
 ('B', '5'): '+',
 ('B', '6'): '+',
 ('B', '7'): '+',
 ('C', '1'): '+',
 ('C', '2'): '+',
 ('C', '3'): '+',
 ('C', '4'): '-',
 ('C', '5'): '+',
 ('C', '6'): '+',
 ('C', '7'): '+',
 ('D', '1'): '+',
 ('D', '2'): '+',
 ('D', '3'): '+',
 ('D', '4'): '-',
 ('D', '5'): '+',
 ('D', '6'): '+',
 ('D', '7'): '+',
 ('E', '1'): '+',
 ('E', '2'): '+',
 ('E', '3'): '+',
 ('E', '4'): '-',
 ('E', '5'): '+',
 ('E', '6'): '+',
 ('E', '7'): '+'}
```

If you want to persist the changes I would pickle the dict:

```
missing = (("B",4),("C",4),("D",4),("E",4))

import os
import pickle
# if file does not exist, this is the first booking
if not os.path.isfile("bookings.pkl"):
    seats = {(x,str(y)):"+" if (x,y) not in missing else "-" for x in ["A","B","C","D","E"] for y in range(1,8)}
else:
    # else use the previous updated dict 
    with open("bookings.pkl") as f:
        seats = pickle.load(f)

while True:
    print("Seats marked + are available\n")
    srt = sorted(seats.iteritems())
    # split into sections based on row and print rows
    sections = [srt[n:n+7] for n in xrange(0,len(srt),7)]
    for sec in sections:
        for seat, status in sec:
             print("{}{}:{status} ".format(*seat,status=status)),
        print("")
    inp = tuple(raw_input("Choose your seat in format row number ie A 1:").upper().split())
    if inp in seats:
        # and not already taken
         if seats[inp] != "*":
            print("You have chosen row: {} seat number: {}\n".format(*inp))
            # ask user to confirm their choice
            confirm = raw_input("Enter y to accept any n to change").lower()
            if confirm == "y":
                seats[inp] = "*"
                with open("bookings.pkl","w") as f:
                    pickle.dump(seats,f)
                    print("Booking confirmed, goodbye.")
                    break
            else:
                 # else let user choose again
                continue
        print("Seat unavailable\n")
    else:
        print("Invalid choice")
```

Comment: oh woh! okay let me give this ago!

Comment: Okay This is pretty neat I will definitely be using this cheers

Comment: @DanielVaughan, no worries I added how to take a booking and persist the changes in the dict, you can make the seating map prettier but I will leave that to you

Answer (score 4):

Just try this:

```
import csv

with open('booking_system.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = [' '] + [str(x) for x in range range(1, 8)]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({' ': 'A', '1': '+', '2': '+', 
                     '3': '+', '4': '+', '5': '+',
                     '6': '+', '7': '+'})
    #And so on...
```

Comment: Thank you this is all I needed I understand from here thank you I can't believe I was getting stuck on this!